# Dimensions of functional integration

Tags: field-theory, dimensional-analysis, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

I'm confused by something super simple. When taking functional variation (e.g. of the action) in the context of field theory, I often see
$$ {\delta \phi(x) \over \delta \phi(y)} = \delta(x-y) \ .$$
How does this make dimensional sense when the LHS naively appears dimensionless, while the RHS has mass dimension 1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Functional derivative and units](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73559/). See also the links therein.

Comment: Because functional derivatives are implicitly computed inside the integral of the functional, which will kill the delta function and the associated units.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/605472/2451